# Wrap TextField into multiple lines when not in editing mode

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to wrap a TextField into multiple lines when it is not being edited.

The following code works fine while the user is in editing mode:

```
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  maxLines: null,
)
```

but when the user leaves the page and comes back, the controller's text inside the TextField is fitted on one line, overflowing horizontally - making it hard for a user to append text. How do I get the text of a TextField to wrap on multiple lines when it is not being edited?

Answer (score 0):

If the textfield is inside a row please wrap it with an flexible or sized box widget.

Edit

Add minLines: 1, and maxLines : 20, by the docs setting it to null means its a single line just displayed in different lines.. setting a minLine and maxLines should work

Comment: That did not solve my issue. The text wraps fine when the user first edits the field. But when the user leaves the page and returns, the text field displays all of the controller's text on one line.